# Foucs on success message displayed in div after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

```
    Div tag in jsp : <div class="okStatusText" id="message"></div>

    code in ajax call:
           if ("SUCCESS" ==result) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Data saved successfully";
     }
```

I am displaying this message at top of the page and I want focus on this message when it is displayed.

Comment: You can try this ...add following statement to your ajax call....document.getElementById("message").focus();

Answer (score 1):

There is no meaning of applying `focus()` on a `div` . Elements like `input` can be made to `focus` by simply doing

```
$('input').focus();
```

It was just an example . In your case , if you want to focus or in actual meaning you want to highlight the message , you can simply change the `background-color` or `color` .

```
 $("#message").html("Data saved successfully").css({'background-color':'blue'});
```

**OR**

```
 $("#message").html("Data saved successfully").css('color','blue');
```

If you want user to see the message directly without scrolling up , try this

```
   $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 50
   },1000);
```

The value 50 can be varibale depending upon upto what height you want to scroll . You can change this value to anything and check at which value it suits your condition . After doing this you can apply css to your message to look more obvious .

Hope i am helpful this time .

Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I am applying css. The message is displayed at top of the page ,user has to scroll to top to see what happened as save button is at bottom of page. How to transfer control/focus to message instead of manually scrolling up.

Comment: I haven't edited my code correct . I haven't set the scroll timer . See now @bharghavivajrala

Comment: Thanks, will implement and let u know.